# Удаление из строки элементов

Tags: javascript

Есть переменная:

```
var d = '<div id="a" class="a">22222222222</div><div class="a">22222222222</div><div class="a">111111111</div><div class="b">55555555555</div><div id="ab" class="a">33333333333</div><div class="b">33333333</div>'
```

Длинна значения переменной всегда меняется (всегда разный набор div). Как в переменной удалить divы с классом 'a'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Регулярками, как-то так
    `var VRegExp = new RegExp(/<div.{1,100}class="a".{1,100}>.{1,100}<\/div>/);`
В фигурных скобках возможное количество произвольных символов.

Answer (score 2):

В конечном итоге у вас должно получиться что-нибудь подобное

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.a').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a" class="a">22222222222</div><div class="a">22222222222</div><div class="a">111111111</div><div class="b">55555555555</div><div id="ab" class="a">33333333333</div><div class="b">33333333</div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно удалить элементы с классом 'a' в самой переменной. В документе существуют другие элементы с классом 'a' удалять их нельзя. Делать индификатор именно в переменной для фильтрации при удалении тоже не желательно